# Can I provide extra context somehow to allow postgres to efficiently sort/limit views without calculating their rows?

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization, view

Given this somewhat contrived query

```
select id, pg_sleep(0.001)::text from administrative_areas;
```

When I add an order and limit to it directly, the sleep executes only once and results are returned quickly.

```
> explain analyze select id, pg_sleep(0.001)::text from administrative_areas order by id desc limit 1;

Limit  (cost=0.28..0.39 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=4.227..4.228 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan Backward using administrative_areas_pkey on administrative_areas  (cost=0.28..69.50 rows=604 width=36) (actual time=4.227..4.227 rows=1 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 1
Planning time: 0.066 ms
Execution time: 4.243 ms
```

If I throw the same query in a view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sleepy AS
    select id, pg_sleep(0.001)::text from administrative_areas;
```

When querying with an order and limit the sleep executes once for every item in the underlaying `administrative_areas` table.

```
> explain analyze select * from sleepy order by id desc limit 1;

Limit  (cost=30.63..30.63 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=3794.827..3794.829 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=30.63..32.14 rows=604 width=36) (actual time=3794.825..3794.825 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: administrative_areas.id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on administrative_areas  (cost=0.00..21.57 rows=604 width=36) (actual time=6.432..3792.566 rows=604 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.072 ms
Execution time: 3794.851 ms
```

Is there any additional context I can add to the view or provide at query time to allow the planner to optimize this?

Comment: you could *not* have a `pg_sleep` in your view statement & add that only when you query to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because pg_sleep is a volatile function.  When you are querying the view, you are in effect, doing this:

```
select id from (select id, pg_sleep(0.001)::text from administrative_areas) order by id desc limit 1;
```

Postgres sees that volatile function in the subquery and runs it for each row.  Let's test this.

```
create table test as select id from generate_series(1, 1000) g(id);
create index on test(id);
analyze test;
create view sleepy as select id, pg_sleep(0.001)::text from test;

explain analyze select * from sleepy order by id desc limit 1;
                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=37.50..37.50 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=1640.368..1640.439 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=37.50..40.00 rows=1000 width=36) (actual time=1640.336..1640.358 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: test.id DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..22.50 rows=1000 width=36) (actual time=1.511..1623.058 rows=1000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.175 ms
 Execution Time: 1640.617 ms
(7 rows)
```

This ran pg_sleep for each row in test, as expected.

Now try a stable function:

```
create function not_so_sleepy() 
  returns void AS 
  $$ 
    select pg_sleep(0.001) 
  $$ language sql 
stable;  -- NOTE: this is just to trick postgres


create view not_as_sleepy as 
  select id, 
  not_so_sleepy()::text 
FROM test;

explain analyze select * 
  from not_as_sleepy 
  order by id desc limit 1;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.28..0.32 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.049..0.198 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using test_id_idx on test  (cost=0.28..43.27 rows=1000 width=36) (actual time=0.024..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning Time: 1.786 ms
 Execution Time: 0.308 ms
(5 rows)
```

In the second case, we told postgres that the function would not have any side-effects so it could safely ignore it.  So, the function must be marked as stable or immutable (and of course, it must be actually stable/immutable) for postgres to not bother running the function.